# OSX Mac Filevault2 prevent shutdown on login screen

Tags: filevault

I recently encrypted my 2014 Mac, OS X 10.9.5, using FileVault2. I noticed that the computer shuts after 5 minutes if there is no activity on the login screen. I believe this is a feature of FileVault2, but I am unable to confirm through Google searches.

If this is the case, is there a setting to prevent shutdown?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274730/is-there-any-way-to-disable-auto-shutdown-from-login-screen-when-no-user-is-logg has sort of an answer.